# Writing to ElasticSearch

Tags: web-access, webservices

Could someone kindly direct me to suitable documentation, Wolfram or otherwise, to connect Mathematica to an ElasticSearch instance. I don't need anything complicated just sufficient to write a record of two numbers and a space separated string which will need tokenising. An improvement would be if I could write out a list of such, around 100mb in size, in one call to ElasticSearch.

Comment: Voted for the reopening. I can answer.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207179/how-to-work-with-elasticsearch-in-mathematica