# How to work with ElasticSearch in Mathematica?

Tags: web-access, webservices

Steps to install and run ElasticSearch:

1. install Java (64-bit): https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
2. download ElasticSearch (https://www.elastic.co/start) and extract archive in `C:\elasticsearch`
3. in Command Prompt: `C:\elasticsearch\bin\elasticsearch.bat`

How we can connect to ElasticSearch from Mathematica, put data in index, make queries?

Comment: Could you expand the question part of this Q/A a bit so it looks more like an actual question?

Comment: Hello @b3m2a1! See my edits. Feel free to edit my question and answer.

Answer (score 13):

**Create the new index `test` and put the data in it:**

```
MapIndexed[
 URLExecute@HTTPRequest[
    <|
     "Domain" -> "localhost", "Port" -> 9200,
     "Path" -> {"test", "external", ToString[First@#2]}
     |>,
    <|
     Method -> "PUT",
     "Body" -> ExportString[<|"Text" -> #1|>, "PythonExpression", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"],
     "ContentType" -> "application/json"
     |>
    ] &,
 (*DATA*){"abc", "def", "ghi"}
 ]
```

> {{"_index" -> "test", "_type" -> "external", "_id" -> "1", 
>     "_version" -> 1, "result" -> "created", 
>     "_shards" -> {"total" -> 2, "successful" -> 1, "failed" -> 0}, 
>     "_seq_no" -> 0, "_primary_term" -> 1}, {"_index" -> "test", 
>     "_type" -> "external", "_id" -> "2", "_version" -> 1, 
>     "result" -> "created", 
>     "_shards" -> {"total" -> 2, "successful" -> 1, "failed" -> 0}, 
>     "_seq_no" -> 1, "_primary_term" -> 1}, {"_index" -> "test", 
>     "_type" -> "external", "_id" -> "3", "_version" -> 1, 
>     "result" -> "created", 
>     "_shards" -> {"total" -> 2, "successful" -> 1, "failed" -> 0}, 
>     "_seq_no" -> 2, "_primary_term" -> 1}}

**Search:**

```
URLExecute@HTTPRequest[
  <|
   "Domain" -> "localhost", "Port" -> 9200,
   "Path" -> {"test", "_search"},
   "Query" -> <|"q" -> "Text: g*"|>
   |>,
  <|Method -> "GET"|>
  ]
```

> {"took" -> 1, "timed_out" -> False, 
>    "_shards" -> {"total" -> 1, "successful" -> 1, "skipped" -> 0, 
>      "failed" -> 0}, 
>    "hits" -> {"total" -> {"value" -> 1, "relation" -> "eq"}, 
>      "max_score" -> 1., 
>      "hits" -> {{"_index" -> "test", "_type" -> "external", 
>         "_id" -> "3", "_score" -> 1., "_source" -> {"Text" -> "ghi"}}}}}

**Delete document from index:**

```
URLExecute@HTTPRequest[
  <|
   "Domain" -> "localhost", "Port" -> 9200,
   "Path" -> {"test", "external", "3"}
   |>,
  <|Method -> "DELETE"|>
  ]
```

> {"_index" -> "test", "_type" -> "external", "_id" -> "3", 
>    "_version" -> 2, "result" -> "deleted", 
>    "_shards" -> {"total" -> 2, "successful" -> 1, "failed" -> 0}, 
>    "_seq_no" -> 3, "_primary_term" -> 1}

**Search again:**

```
URLExecute@HTTPRequest[
  <|
   "Domain" -> "localhost", "Port" -> 9200,
   "Path" -> {"test", "_search"},
   "Query" -> <|"q" -> "Text: g*"|>
   |>,
  <|Method -> "GET"|>
  ]
```

> {"took" -> 2, "timed_out" -> False, 
>    "_shards" -> {"total" -> 1, "successful" -> 1, "skipped" -> 0, 
>      "failed" -> 0}, 
>    "hits" -> {"total" -> {"value" -> 0, "relation" -> "eq"}, 
>      "max_score" -> Null, "hits" -> {}}}

**Delete index:**

```
URLExecute@HTTPRequest[
  <|
   "Domain" -> "localhost", "Port" -> 9200,
   "Path" -> {"test"}
   |>,
  <|"Method" -> "DELETE"|>
  ]
```

> {"acknowledged" -> True}